# How to run a test on a specific IP using Selenium Grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

i have a few queries regarding Selenium Grid.

Consider the below scenario:

Machine A:
registered as hub by command=

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar -role hub
```

Machine B:having Windows 7 and chrome browser

registered as node by command=`java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="path of chrome driver" –jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar –role webdriver –hub http://ipnameofHub:4444/grid/register -port 5566`

Machine C: having Windows 7 and chrome browser​

registered as node​ by command=`java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="path of chrome driver" –jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar –role webdriver –hub http://ipnameofHub:4444/grid/register -port 5566`

Machine D: having Windows 7 and chrome browser​

registered as node​ by command=`java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="path of chrome driver" –jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar –role webdriver –hub http://ipnameofHub:4444/grid/register -port 5566`

```
DesiredCapabilities dc=new DesiredCapabilities();

dc.setBrowserName("chrome");

dc.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);

​WebDriver driver=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"),dc);
```

When i run a test, which node will grid choose and on what basis, since all the nodes have the same platform and browser as specified in the DesiredCapabilities.

Is the node randomly chosen or the first node matching the DesiredCpabilities is chosen?

Question No.2

If i want to run a test on specifically Machine D, how can that be done.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. it is chosen based on first matching capability and available node.
2. To run on specific node, you can write your own algorithm to choose. the following link may help to write custom capability matcher https://www.assertthat.com/posts/make_your_selenium_grid_nodes_personalized